# The more times you watch that movie the better it gets

Tags: expressions

> The more **times** you watch that movie the better it gets.

Is this sentence correct? You know when you watch the same movie for the second time and discover small details that you didn't notice on the first time, which makes it even better. And so when you watch it the third, fourth, etc. time.

Is there a better or more common way to say that? Perhaps:

> The more **often** you watch that movie the better it gets.

Comment: I’d use “times” if I was implying that the number of times you’ve watched it is the key.  I’d use “often” if implying the frequency of watching is important- once a week instead of once a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. The more times you watch that movie the better it gets.
> 2. The more often you watch that movie the better it gets.

Both are correct grammatically but they have different meanings.

1 means that you have watched the movie a number of times and each time it seemed better

2 means that you regularly watch the movie and the more frequently you watch it, the better it gets. Thus if you watch it daily instead of weekly, it will get better faster!

1 is what I would expect in normal conversation.

Comment: What does "The more you watch it, the better it gets" mean then?

Comment: @Mari-Lou - It's ambiguous but the context usually makes the meaning clear.

Comment: They're interchangeable in real English.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the movie **grew on** you. From Lexico:

> **[grow on](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grow_on)**: Become gradually more appealing to (someone)

The more times I watched *John Wick*, the more it **grew on** me. It's a common way to say, "The more times I watched that movie, the better I thought it was."

Comment: I look at “grew on me” as starting from a position of dislike.  I would not say that A movie that I loved the first time I saw it and that kept revealing more and more subtleties had grown on me.  It would “keep getting better and better”

Comment: @Jim Fair point. Thanks.